# Simple Multithreading Program Issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, thread-safety

I just started reading about multithreading and tried to write a very simple program in C++.

The problem is my three threads try to print at the same time, messing up my output. The output is different each time.

To combat this, I added a 1 second delay in each infinite loop which remedied the issue for the most part. However, every run, one line executes before another should (explained further below).

My ideal output would be:

```
Calc1 Result: __
count1: __
Calc2 Result: __
count2: __
Calc3 Result: __
count3: __
```

And have that repeat forever

My code and some examples of different outputs are below.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void calc1(int num) {
    int count1 = 0;
    while (true) {
        printf(" Calc1 Result = %d\n", num + 1);
        ++count1;
        printf("count1 = %d\n", count1);
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
    }

}

void calc2(int num) {
    int count2 = 0;
    while (true) {
        printf(" Calc2 Result = %d\n", num + 2);
        ++count2;
        printf("count2 = %d\n", count2);
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}

void calc3(int num) {
    int count3 = 0;
    while (true) {
        printf(" Calc3 Result = %d\n", num + 3);
        ++count3;
        printf("count3 = %d\n", count3);
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}

int main()
{
    thread one(calc1, 25);
    thread two(calc2, 50);
    thread three(calc3, 100);

    
    one.join();
    two.join();
    three.join();

    
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

Sometimes the output starts with one of the functions executing and sometimes the other.

For example here are the first 12 lines of output for 2 different runs.

1.
The first 6 lines here are perfect. But then, Calc3 runs before Calc1 and Calc2 in the lines 7-12 of this output.

```
 Calc1 Result = 26
count1 = 1
 Calc2 Result = 52
count2 = 1
 Calc3 Result = 103
count3 = 1
 Calc3 Result = 103
 Calc1 Result = 26
count1 = 2
count3 = 2
 Calc2 Result = 52
count2 = 2
```

2. 

Three things here:

First, the output is different than my first run. (Lines 1-6 are the same, after that are different)

Second, the loops run in the undesired order again. Calc3 then Calc2 then Calc1 instead of 1 2 3.

Third, Calc3 and Calc2 results appear back to back (Lines 7, 8) but what I want is the result and count for each loop to appear back to back. I know this specific issue could be fixed by combining the result and counter printf statements, but I prefer to have the separate printf statements. Is there another way to fix this?

```
 Calc1 Result = 26
count1 = 1
 Calc2 Result = 52
count2 = 1
 Calc3 Result = 103
count3 = 1
 Calc3 Result = 103
 Calc2 Result = 52
count2 = 2
count3 = 2
 Calc1 Result = 26
count1 = 2
```

Does anyone know if this is supposed to happen? And if so, why is it happening?

Also, if there are any recommended resources (videos, books, or articles) please link them.

Thank you in advance :D

Comment: The threads operate independently, so there is no output order you could expect. If you want something ordered between threads, you have to do so explicitly. For example, you could implement a producer/consumer scenario, where the consumer takes the results and prints them.

Comment: The entire point of multithreading is parallel processing, so having the threads run operations in order is against what they're for. Maybe you aren't looking for a multi-threading solution for your issue, there is no easy way to order threads to do work. It defeats the purpose.

Comment: And you have 3 counters (`count1`, `count2` and `count3`) that you increase by one so you will get 3 of each number. If you want to synchronize events you need to use some of the synchronizing primitives, like `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable`. The three `calc` functions also look like they could be combined into one, that you call 3 times. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/T4Yr69P69)